# xCode 9: UITextView not initialized

Tags: uitextview, xcode9

Once I switched to xCode 9, my initialization of a UITextView stopped working:

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtPirepText: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{

   if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad
   {

       self.txtPirepText = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 380, width: 900, height: 280))

       print("IS THIS VALUE NIL? ",self.txtPirepText)
       self.txtPirepText.text = ""

       self.txtPirepText.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 17)
       self.txtPirepText.textColor = UIColor.black
   }
}
```

The print shows that the value is nil and the application crashes on trying to set a text.
Does such initialization not work any more? Thank you!

Comment: Typically you do not initilize an IBOutlet , usually you let the bundle initilize it

Comment: Thank you. Interesting, the code worked fine before...